# Json.stringify() is ignoring a object property after xlsx.sheet_to_json

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I'm using the SheetJs library to read an Excel file.

```
 const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet])
```

Which returns objects like this.

```
{webShop: 'AR_APPD-72642_RDS_Retailer_User', __EMPTY: '',
  webShop: ""
  __EMPTY: ""
  __EMPTY_2: "AR_APPD-72642_RDS_Retailer_User (Prod)"
  __EMPTY_3: "AR_APPD-72642_RDS_Retailer_User (Prod) "
  __EMPTY_4: "RtailerUI"
  __EMPTY_5: "RtailerUI"
  __rowNum__: 58
```

[image]

Ignoring the other properties.

The property **rowNum** is created by the sheet_to_json function and returns the Excel row Number of the Object.

I then use `JSON.stringify`to create the JSON string of a single excel sheet. Which I string concatenate to a previous sheet.

```
this.convertedJson= this.convertedJson +JSON.stringify(data,undefined, 4);
```

Now the problem I'm encountering. After using `.stringify()` I get returned every single property the different rows have, except **rowNum**.

This is the part of the output String for the Object above.

```
{
        "WebShop": "AR_APPD-72642_RDS_RetailerUI_User",
        "__EMPTY": "",
        "__EMPTY_2": "AR RDS Retailer UI User (Prod)",
        "__EMPTY_3": "AR RDS Retailer UI User (Prod) ",
        "__EMPTY_4": "RtailerUI",
        "__EMPTY_5": "RtailerAI"
    }
```

I've found an older changelog of SheetJs, where I've noticed that the **rowNum** property was changed from enumerable to non-enumerable. Following up on that lead, apparently you cant serialize non-enumerable properties with .stringify(). Does anyone know a simple solution how I can still use .stringify() with non-enumerable properties. Or how I can change all **rowNum** properties of every object to enumerable?

Comment: Only enumerable own properties are picked by `stringify` method. `__rowNum__` is probably a non-enumerable property (because it's greyed out)

Comment: Concatenating one JSON string to another does not make sense; you end up with invalid JSON.

Comment: Make a new object, and then add the props manually that don't serialise, you can start of with `const j={...data}; j.__rowNum__ = data.__rowNum__;`  You can then stringify `j`.

Comment: @Pointy they are valid after a bit of string manipulation

Comment: @adiga yeah thanks for confirmation, was my suspicion too

Comment: @Keith can u explain a little more, i dont think i understand what your tryna say. I have 11 sheets with 100s of rows of data. Simply adding a row property to each object is not an option im afraid. Do you mean basically "copy" each object and add the __rowNum__ to the copy?

Comment: Another option is to loop through all the objects changing the `__rowNum__` property to enumerable with `Object.defineProperty()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated before, if the property is not enumerable it wont be picked by `JSON.stringify`. So you need to copy each object as @Keith says or redefine the property to enumerable as @Barmar states.

I would like to add here, if you opt for redefine the property, and if the property is configurable

Knowing beforehand the name of the property you can add a custom stringify function

```
nonEnumStringify = (obj) => {
const nonEnumObj = JSON.stringify(obj, (key, val) => {
    if (!key) {
        if (typeof val === 'object' && val.hasOwnProperty('__rowNum__')) {
            Object.defineProperty(val, '__rowNum__', {
                value: val.__rowNum__,
                enumerable: true,
            });
        }
    }
    return val;
});
return nonEnumObj;}
```

And then simply call `nonEnumStringify(data)` instead of the standard `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Thanks for explaining the suggestions given above in a  little more detail. Ill give both a try today. I'll mark your answer as accepted